# jsTree - multiple checkboxes on the same item

Tags: html, jstree

I am seeking for a possibility to put two check-boxes on the same item in a jsTree. Could any one help me?

It should look like this:

[image: screenshot]

A peace of code would be great.

Thank you very much!
Vaio

Comment: any update on this!!?

Comment: @ShaMoh: I actually haven't figured out a suitable solution for multiple check boxes, but solved the problem in another way. I implemented a context menu that is viewed on the right click. In that context menu the user can check or un-check the 'Lead' property. I'm still interested in tipps for the multiple checkboxes in a jsTree. So please post, if you know some. Thank you.